# Windows 11 not resolving .local addresses using mDNS

Tags: windows, bonjour, mdns, zeroconf

I am broadcasting a new mqtt-service via mDNS. My Flutter app is notified that a new service was registered but I am problems with the name-resolution of the address called MyMqttService.mqtt.local

Name resolution is working fine on MacOS and iOS devices, but Windows is not able to convert the .local adress.

I have already installed Bonjour Printer Services from Apple, using dns-sd and so on. But nothing helped me to get Windows 11 to resolve the .local adresses via ping.

Windows firewall is also deactived, so that should not be a reason.

Comment: Make sure you restart windows. If any change is made to network configuration it can break the dns client service. This will never recover and can not be restarted. You have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found you can't use double dot in .local mdns names. In your case it is .mqtt.local and it will not work. Try to remove mqtt part from the hostname :)